# Need help to understand why was my post edit rejected

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, rejected-edits, specific-edit

I *need* help to understand why was my post edit rejected -

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/21672360

Is there a rejection reason?

Comment: The OP rolled back his question after the required 2 people approve the edit. Probably because OP likes to ask LQ questions I would assume.

Comment: That's a turd. Don't polish them.

Comment: so OP can reject my edit? I didn't know that... what if its first question?

Comment: The OP can always reject an edit

Comment: Upvoting not because the edit was good, but because this question (despite the non-descriptive title) might be useful for future viewers.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The author of the post rejected it. They didn't leave a reason, but I'd guess they thought you changed the character of their post. Notably, your biggest change was in replacing their jumbled and non-descriptive title ("I have a method which returns Pane and On that pane are some button and ProgressBar everything work perfectly") with an even *less* descriptive title ("Starting download in new line?") and then putting the former title as the introduction to the post body. I'd also guess English isn't their first language.

This is... Not a very good question. I wouldn't recommend even bothering to edit it. But if you *are* going to edit it, [try to make the author look good](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53749963/timeline#history_7d0b9c4a-a8dc-4be2-8b20-2eb2cd41ae0b):

[image: image of the edit I just made, for illustrative purposes]

If that looks like too much work... Then as Will suggests, don't waste your time trying to polish turds.

Comment: It may also have been a misclick from the OP.

Comment: *"if you are going to edit it, try to make the author look good"* is fantastic advice for editing posts. We should repeat it as often as possible. :-)