# Why was my noise reduction edit rejected?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, rejected-edits, specific-edit

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/25569803

I removed the noise from this very short post and mentioned that it was just noise reduction. Why was my edit rejected? Are there some special rules I need to follow if I am below 2000 reputation and I want to remove noise from posts?

Comment: "Don't polish turds" comes to mind. If all it does is link to another SO answer, it's a duplicate, not a good answer. Editing and asking that others review an edit on a post that is... bleh... isn't great.

Comment: I always understood "Don't polish turds" to mean posts which need to be deleted. I don't know if this answer should be deleted.

Comment: the question should be closed as a duplicate. The answer is what? "go there for your answer". That means the proper thing is to close as a dupe. So yes, imho, that should be deleted.

Comment: It's a pretty minor edit, on a pretty short and not so useful answer. The reviewers might have felt you are wasting your own time (which they don't care about) *and* theirs (which they *do* care about).

Comment: In the end, only the reviewers why the chose to reject your edit. The only thing any of us can tell you is if we would have rejected it or not. Personally, I would have approved it. Maybe would have taken a look at the Q&A later to decide if I had to raise flag on the answer or cast a close-vote on the question.

Comment: Like @yivi, I also would have approved this edit. I also would have closed the question as a duplicate, and then deleted the duplicate answer. I did the latter two things, which makes it pointless to have done the first (since deleting the answer also deletes any edits that were made to it).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I was one of the reviewers who rejected the [edit suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/25569803).  I'll own my reasons and let the community admonish me as they will. I do make mistakes.

My hope for this answer is that it (1) answers your question and (2) serves as a catalyst for myself, the OP, and future visitors to learn from this event. **Like I said, I do make mistakes, and I can only answer the question honestly from how I reviewed it at the time.**

> *Why was my noise reduction edit rejected?*

I rejected the edit because the answer itself is quite poor and the edit suggestion was not of such importance that, in my opinion, warranted creating work for reviewers in the Edit Review Queue.

I do believe the text

> Hope that helps:)

is eligible for removal. However, no other edits of substance were made to the answer, which conflicted with [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/377819/8239061). I suspect that answer will be deleted and that would not have been staved off through the suggested edit.<sup>[1]</sup>

I acknowledge that others might have approved it ([1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394547/why-was-my-noise-reduction-edit-rejected/394549#comment759354_394547), [2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394547/why-was-my-noise-reduction-edit-rejected/394549#comment759351_394547)). With different context, I have [approved an edit like this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/25571104) by the OP.

---

**Related:**

I try to keep in mind a few answers from [Shog9](https://stackoverflow.com/users/811/shog9) for my Edit Reviews:<sup>[2]</sup>

- [When to Improve or Reject edit suggestions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265302/8239061).
- [Don't waste time polishing turds, but if you do, make the author look good](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/377819/8239061).

<sub>[1] I should have acted on the answer itself ([see this comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394547/why-was-my-noise-reduction-edit-rejected/394549#comment759366_394549)).</sub>
<sub>[2] Summary text for each link mine.</sub>

Comment: I downvoted this answer because you did not express hope that it would be found helpful.

Comment: Unless something changed, when you erdit posts that are in the Low Quality review queue, it automatically kicks it out of the queue.  So makes deleting problematic content harder

Comment: @CodyGray I appreciate the feedback.  And you are right.  I was in the process of improving the answer and I trust edits have been helpful in that regard. I believe in taking responsibility for one's actions, and my original post emphasized that maybe a bit too much.

Comment: (I do hope you know my first comment was tongue-in-cheek.) My bigger concern is not how you handled the edit, but that you didn’t flag the answer or the question in any way to indicate the problems with it. You said that you suspect the answer would be deleted. Indeed, it should have been. But it only was because I saw this Meta question. Otherwise, it would have stuck around even longer.

Comment: @CodyGray I accept that.  And you are right.  I felt uncomfortable with the tag and confirming it was indeed a duplicate.  I suppose I could have dropped into SOCVR, but I typically only go to SOCVR when I'm already very sure about what to do. I accept your feedback.  Thanks.

Comment: @CodyGray no, I didn't catch that you were joking.  sigh.   Well, the edit I made in response doesn't hurt anything, I hope.

Comment: @psubsee2003 I'm not following your comment. I don't believe this was edited in the VLQ queue (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/11393191/timeline)).

Comment: Not saying it was in the queue.  But in a general statement to reinforce your "related" section editing low quality posts like this will actually make deleting harder because an edit removes it from the Low Quality Queue.  So rejecting is absolutely the right idea

Comment: This has been a useful answer. :) I now agree the edit should be rejected and the post flagged as NAA or using a custom reason. I should have probably done so myself, I just didn't think it was bad enough to warrant a deletion. The edit would have been invalidated anyway if you flagged it and if mod deleted it, so approving it would not be so bad either, it would just send a mixed signal. We need to remember that flagging a post is also an option in suggested-edits review queue.

Comment: Yeah, the joke was you should have ended your answer with something like, *"Hope that helps"*. Sometimes my sense of humor is obtusely quirky.

Comment: @CodyGray that made me laugh.  Indeed. I completely missed a great opportunity.